# Generators + Promises explanation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I've been studying Promises and Generators but I got stuck in the script below:

```
function getFile(file) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        fakeAjax(file, resolve);
    });
}

function* getFiles() {
    var p1 = getFile('file1');
    var p2 = getFile('file2');
    var p3 = getFile('file3');

    output(yield p1);
    output(yield p2);
    output(yield p3);
}

function runner(gen) {
    var g = gen();
    function run(val) {
        val || undefined;
        var next = g.next(val);
        if(!next.done && !next.value !== undefined) {
            next.value
                .then(function(v) {
                    run(v);
                });
        }
    }
    run();
}

runner(getFiles);
```

What I'm trying to figure it out is what happens when I get to the first yield on getFiles? Why does this code work, I don't get it.

*EDIT: output is simply a console.log wrappend in a function. The fakeAjax function returns a text from an object based on the 'file' requested.

Comment: what is `output` function? MDN has excellent documentation for both generators and promises (not sure which of those you don't understand) - I'd suggest reading the documentation at MDN - or https://www.promisejs.org/generators/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm trying to figure it out is what happens when I get to the first yield on getFiles? Why does this code work, I don't get it.

`yield` does three things:

1. It pause the execution of the generator function
2. It defines the value the caller of `next()` will receive in the `value` property. In this case, that's the promises you made.
3. It optionally acts as an expression with the value passed into `next()`. That will be the file name you passed as a argument to `next()`.

`yield` is like a two-way conduit, both accepting values and passing values.

In your code at the first `yield` it will return the object with the promise and pause, but it doesn't log anything to the console at this point — `yield` can pause mid-expression. When you call `next()` again it will finish the console.log and then move to the next `yield`. It can be a little confusing because there is usually one more call to `next` that there are `yields`. For example in this code `next is called four times and that's why you get the last console.log.

Here's an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I assume approximates the undefined functions in your example:

```js
function getFile(file) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(file), 1000))
}

function* getFiles() {
    var p1 = getFile('file1');
    var p2 = getFile('file2');
    var p3 = getFile('file3');

    console.log(yield p1); // return promise, then pause, then log value passed to next()
    console.log(yield p2);
    console.log(yield p3);
}

function runner(gen) {
    var g = gen();
    function run(val) {
        var next = g.next(val);     
        if(!next.done && !next.value !== undefined) {
            next.value
                .then(function(v) {
                    run(v);
                });
        }     
    }
    run();
}

runner(getFiles);
```